# How to make 2 line text in a Toast go centered to each other?

Tags: java, android, text, center, android-toast

Is it posible to center the first word "Λάθος" on top of the rest of the Toast?

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Λάθος"+"\nΣωστή απάντηση: "+mAnswere, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 4):

you can set gravity to the textview inside the toast

```
Toast vwToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Λάθος"+"\nΣωστή απάντηση: "+mAnswere, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
TextView tv = (TextView) vwToast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
if( tv != null) {
  tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
vwToast.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

just use the "`\n`"-tag like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "line #1"+"\n"+"line #2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Correct me if im wrong ?! But gravity is already set to center as per default in every toast's...